# HappyBase installation on multinode cluster

Tags: hbase, cloudera, happybase, bigdata

I have a multinode cluster with cloudera hbase. It has:

- 1 master,
- 5 thrift servers,
- 5 region servers,
- 1 gateway

On what of these servers I have to install **happybase**? I've read the happybase doc, but didn't find this information.

I need to read and write into base. Is it enough to install happybase only on Gateway server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

happybase author here.

you only need to install happybase on the application servers where your python programs will run. those python programs will connect to the thrift server(s).